# Array.map is not a function (datalist wont update)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I've been folowing along with this tutorial series on youtube but I keep running into this error (the link to the tutorial can be found here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=re3OIOr9dJI&t=11s&ab_channel=PedroTech) .

The app is supposed to pull information from a mysql database and add it to the web page whenever a new entry is loaded, but instead I get the following error "TypeError: movieReviewList.map is not a function".

To my knowledge The error's occuring because the object (movieReviewList) isn't being instantiated and javascript doesn't recognize it as an Array.

Front end code:

```
import './App.css';
import Axios from 'axios';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
//import bodyParser from 'body-parser';



function App() {

  //get movie name/review from form
  const [movieName,setMovieName] = useState('')
  const [review, setReview] = useState('')
  const [movieReviewList, setMovieList] = useState([])
  //const [number, setNumber] = useState('')
  useEffect(()=>
  { 
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/get").then((response) =>{
    //setNumber(2);
    //console.log(number);
    setMovieList(response.data)
    console.log(movieReviewList);
    //console.log("stuff");
    //console.log(response.data);
    })
  }, []);
  const submitReview =  () => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/insert", {
      movieName: movieName,  
      movieReview: review
    }).then( (setMovieList(...movieReviewList, {movieName: movieName, movieReview: review})))
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Crud tutorial</h1>
      <div className="form">
      <label htmlFor="getName">Movie Name</label>
      <input placeholder="movie name" type="text" id="getName" onChange={(e)=>{
        setMovieName(e.target.value)
      }}/>
      <label>Movie review</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="review" onChange={(e)=>{setReview(e.target.value)}}/>
      <button onClick={submitReview} >Submit</button>


    
      {
      
        movieReviewList.map( (val) =>
        { 
          return <h1>Movie: {val.movieName} | Movie Review: {val.movieReview}</h1>
        })
      
        }
      
      
      
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

back end:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const cors = require("cors");

const mySql = require('mySql');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
//const { urlencoded } = require('body-parser');

//bodyparsers is causing conflicts with express? 
//app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded);
//app.use(bodyParser.json);

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json())
//app.use(bodyParser);
//resolves cors permission error
app.use(cors());

const db = mySql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'cruddatabase'
});


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("crud database root")
});


//called recursively
app.get('/api/get', (req, res) => { 
    const sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM movie_reviews";
    db.query(sqlSelect, (err, result) =>{
        console.log("recursion test");
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        else    //"res" was already defined within this scope, which is why I use "result"
        {
            console.log('get operation was successful');
            res.send(result); //json file sent to the front end upon successful query

        }
    });
    
});
app.post('/api/insert', (req, res) => {
    
    const movieName = req.body.movieName;
    const movieReview = req.body.movieReview;
    
    //(?,?) serves as a placeholder 
    const sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO movie_reviews (movieName, movieReview) VALUES (?, ?)";
    db.query(sqlInsert, [movieName, movieReview],  (err, result) => {
        console.log("insert operation successful");
    });
});


//because port 3000 is in use

app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log('server activated on port 3001');
});
```

Comment: What do you have in your `console.log(response.data);`??

Answer (score 0):

On the submit review you are missing square brackets:

you need to change it to:

```js
const submitReview =  () => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/insert", {
      movieName: movieName,  
      movieReview: review
    }).then( (setMovieList([...movieReviewList, {movieName: movieName, movieReview: review}])))
  };
```

The reason this is happening is because you are changing it `movieList` from an array to an object. I would suggest you read up on [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
res.status(200).json(results);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I don't mean to be rude but i just discovered I'd written the "...setMovieList etc." part differently to how the tutor wrote it so I'm now getting a different error. 

I'll give your response a go though